# android-maven-plugin 3.2.0 with maven 3.0.4 not compile it

Tags: android, eclipse, maven

When I try compile with maven 3.0.4, Eclipse give me this error:

> Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.2.0:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) on project Proyect: The plugin com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.0.0 requires Maven version [3.0.3,) -> [Help 1]
>   [ERROR]

I don't understand because I have maven 3.0.4, m2Eclipse plugin and when I test with 2.x versions yes compile it.

Comment: Try it from the command line, that'll prove if your project is broken, or if the eclipse plugins are broken. Open a terminal in the project area where the pom.xml is and type `mvn clean install`. If that works, you have maven 3.0.4 installed correctly and its just eclipse playing funny business...

Comment: Are you sure you are actually using android-maven-plugin 3.2.0 in all module projects? it looks weird as it complain about android-maven-plugin 3.0.0.

Comment: I've tried since console and all is fine. But inside eclipse it not running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you really sure you're compiling using Maven 3.0.4? Maybe you have your Maven 3.0.4 on disk, but use m2e's embedded Maven 3.0.2 (which is default). Go to `Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Installations` to check which Maven version you have set up.

Comment: I have changed it but it happens same error. Maybe it is because in a note down Installations says: Embedded runtime is always used for dependency resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://rgladwell.github.com/m2e-android/) will help after that, there is an issue with the android connector for which there's a [fix](https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/issues/89). Atleast it did for me!