# The plugin com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.1.1 requires Maven version [3.0.3,)

Tags: android, maven

I'm having an issue when building my android project in Eclipse. The error is:

```
Build errors for MyAndroidProject; org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.1.1:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) on project MyAndroidProject: The plugin com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.1.1 requires Maven version [3.0.3,)
```

This is my Pom.xml plugin:

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

The point is that I am using maven 3.0.3 in my local environment and in my Eclipse.

```
Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 18:31:09+0100)
```

Any idea where this error comes from and how to solve it?

Many thanks in advance ;)

Ruben

Comment: Have you set up M2_HOME environment variable, check out [here](http://maven.apache.org/download.html) for how to set up.

Comment: Yes, I have set up environment variables, restarted the computer, etc...but the issue persists :(

Comment: Looks like m2e plugin keep using its embedded Maven (version 3.0.2) instead of your installed one, see if the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031709/android-maven-plugin-3-2-0-with-maven-3-0-4-not-compile-it) helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the build from a custom run configuration in Eclipse you may need to specify what Maven runtime to use. Try downloading Maven 3.0.4 and add it as a custom Maven runtime in Eclipse then select the 3.0.4 Maven runtime under Run Configurations for your particular build.

I remember having problems also with the embedded 3.0.3 while 3.0.4 works fine.